# Retrieve processes information remote computer using C#

Tags: c#, process

I'm developing a desktop application using C# language. I'm trying to retrieve all the current active processes on the remote computer with the following code:

```
else if (infocomboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                string compname = compnameLabel.Text;
                Process[] remoteAll = Process.GetProcesses(compnameLabel.Text);
                foreach (Process process in remoteAll)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(process.ProcessName);
                    item.Tag = process;
                    listProcessView.Items.Add(item);
                }

            }
```

I put the code inside the button_click function.

I can't seem to retrieve it with an error saying "InvalidOperationException was unhandled"
"Couldn't connect to remote machine"

Log in username and password is disabled on the remote computer. Firewall and antivirus are off also.

Refer below for the error screenshot

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8GUZ.png)

What is exactly the problem? Can anybody give solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I guess `compNameLabel.Text` will be the label in front of the textbox. you need to read the value from the text box, not from its label.

Comment: That label contains the name of the remote machine that was retrieved earlier. But this code works on the local machine though.

Comment: is the remote computer a member of a domain? if so, of the same computer domain as the calling machine?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to verify from a command line that the hostname is resolvable.

```
ping theOtherComputerName
```

If that resolves to an IP address and responds then you've eliminated one possible issue. Next up would have to be connection issues.

I believe the GetProcesses command tries to login to the remote machine using the current username and password, so you would need the same username and password on the other machine,

OR you'll need to impersonate an admin user on the remote machine doing something like this [impersonate user in c#](https://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/)